# using a field of one class in another class in forms.py

Tags: django, forms

I have 2 classes in forms.py, I want to access one of those classes inside another class. Something like below-

```
class A(forms.ModelForm):
filename = forms.FileField(label='Select a file')

  class Meta:
      model = File
      fields = ('filename',)

class B(forms.ModelForm):
filename = A

  class Meta:
      model = Rack
      fields = ('rack',)
```

Both of the classes are using different models (I cannot modify models.py). I want a field filename in class B that is sort of creating a widget from class A, basically want the same filename atrribute from class A in class B. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the filename through the class because the attribute "filename" is associated with the *objects* of A, not the class A.

[See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for how to create class variables in Python, and you can see why it's impossible to access the form field filename like that.]

I don't see why you would want to get the filename field from class A, and I didn't understand what you meant by "basically want the same filename atrribute from class A in class B." If you simply want the same FileField, you could always just do:

```
filename = forms.FileField(label='Select a file')
```

in class B as well.